# Python Regular Expression

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to Python and regular expression. All the examples I've found online appear to be very ambiguous and vague.
For example, in these few entries.

```
     2016-01-15T11:40:00-08:00 Valedictorian candidates meet for instructions
     2016-02-26T15:05:00-08:00 Valedictorian written submissions due
     2016-03-17 St. Patrick's Day
     2016-03-25 Good Friday
     2016-03-27 Easter Sunday
```

I want the end result to be similar to the last 3 entries. (Removing the time, noted by TXX:XX:XX-XX:XX)
while also preserving the summary.
If anyone could tell me how to program this in a simple way in python or give me some pointers, it would be much appreciated.

Edit:
The data is being stored in a simple .txt file that was outputted through python as well, as the python program grabs values from Google Calendars in above output. But I want to have the regex within it as well to remove the time format. 
Also. Google doesn't allow removing the time/putting it in another timedate format, as far as I know.

Edit2:
**All entries are in output.txt**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you would have to show how this data is being stored, maybe some code of what you have tried so far and such.

Comment: you can also do this without regex and instead using string slicing since the characters you want to remove seem to be at a specific index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>> import re
>> value = """2016-01-15T11:40:00-08:00 Valedictorian candidates meet for instructions
... 2016-02-26T15:05:00-08:00 Valedictorian written submissions due
... 2016-03-17 St. Patrick's Day
... 2016-03-25 Good Friday
... 2016-03-27 Easter Sunday
... """

>> re.sub(r'T[\d:-]+ ', ' ', v)

"2016-01-15 Valedictorian candidates meet for instructions\n2016-02-26 Valedictorian written submissions due\n2016-03-17 St. Patrick's Day\n2016-03-25 Good Friday\n2016-03-27 Easter Sunday\n"
```

Comment: Look at your results. You're only returning the last word of the text, not the entire text.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the answer :-).

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the matches to this regex(Which denotes the time) -

```
T(?:\d+(?:-\d+)?:){3}\d+
```

with an empty string.
 
[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/lO7jW5/1)


The code would look like this  -

```
In [13]: s='''2016-01-15T11:40:00-08:00 Valedictorian candidates meet for instructions
2016-02-26T15:05:00-08:00 Valedictorian written submissions due
2016-03-17 St. Patrick's Day
2016-03-25 Good Friday
2016-03-27 Easter Sunday'''

In [14]: import re

In [15]: new_str = re.sub(r'T(?:\d+(?:-\d+)?:){3}\d+', '', s)

In [16]: print new_str
2016-01-15 Valedictorian candidates meet for instructions
2016-02-26 Valedictorian written submissions due
2016-03-17 St. Patrick's Day
2016-03-25 Good Friday
2016-03-27 Easter Sunday
```